# How to connect to an interface hosting a virtual network on Linux

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, network-interface

I am running VMware on a Linux host. The virtual machines on this network are connected via NAT, which as I understand means that my Linux host is acting as a router/DHCP server and leasing IP addresses to them. On my host terminal `ifconfig` gives the following:

```
$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5386  bytes 18526190 (17.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5386  bytes 18526190 (17.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.166.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.166.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 942  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 61  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.205  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2600:6c40:4500:40f:9e15:c6b2:3231:ece3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2600:6c40:4500:40f:0:503f:2af0:9b2c  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::c3cf:50e4:f85:fad6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 28165  bytes 21865045 (20.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17881  bytes 2988789 (2.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I am connected to wifi currently through interface `wlp1s0`, is it possible to instead connect to the interface `vmnet8`? Specifically I would like to be able to run `nmap` and `metasploit` against the virtual machines from my host computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so directly by only `nmap`-ing the IP address pool of the NAT. It appears that is 192.168.166.XXX - where XXX is obviously 0 to 254 (or also shown as 192.168.166.1/24). Running a scan on that subnet would route all through the NAT virtual adapter, and similarly, running it against the 192.168.1.XXX/24 subnet will go through your home LAN.

Since your host is also effectively part of the NAT it's hosting (i.e. we know this since it has an IP address from it) its only a matter of scanning that specific 192.168.166.XXX subnet in nmap or whatever you choose. The same goes for `metasploit` - for example, you might run an `smb2` scan by `SET RHOSTS 192.168.166.0-192.168.166.254` and this would be sufficient. I recommend you to also `SET THREADS=50` if you don't like your time wasted :)